# Run time of 2 nested while loops

Tags: runtime, nested, while-loop

I had another question regarding loops. I know 2 for loops make the run time O(n^2) since you iterate through the list n * n times.

But what about two while loops?

```
While (array1 is not empty)

    if(~~~)
        do ~~~
    else(~~~)
        do ~~~

  while (array2 is not empty)

    if(~~~)
        do ~~~
    else(~~~)
        do ~~~
```

so a while loop is nested inside another while loop. Does this make the run time n^2 also since we iterate  though the first loop n times and second loop n times? Any help would be apreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to indicate how the iteration happens - does each trip through the loop reduce the size of both arrays?

Comment: Also, O(n^2) indicates the time complexity, not the run time - run time depends on what you're doing, and you can work it out with `time`/a profiler/a stop watch/a calendar.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it doesn't look like they are nested. There are 2 loops, separated by an if/else. In this case, it would be O(n).

If the while loops were nested and based on input size, it would indeed be O(n^2). It's not important what 'type' of loop you are using, but rather the fact that you're looping over the input of size n.

Comment: I think you need a better code example, it looks like you are consecutively going through 2 arrays. I assumed this in my answer above. A better code example would help clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

A nested for loop runs at O(n²), as you said.  The notation for determining how fast two of these in sequence will run is O(2n²).  The notation for running two while loops n times each is O(2n).

Comment: Hello, I figured it out now. Thank you. I think my editing was a mistake since the 2nd while loop was supposed to be inside the first while loop. But I understand the problem now, thank you everyone.

Answer (score -1):

```
while (array1 isn't empty){
     while (array2 isn't empty){
         //code goes here
     }
}
```

If the first array has n elements and the 2nd array has m elements then the runtime is O( n * m )

In the special case where n and m are the same, then it is O( n * n )

```
while (array1 isn't empty){
//code
}

while (array2 isn't empty){
//code
}
```

In this case the runtime is O(n) + O(m) which is O(n) if n is greater than or equal to m and O(m) if m is greater than or equal to n.

Comment: You can't just write `while` instead of `for` and use the `for` loop syntax. A `while` loop in virtually every language that has one takes only a boolean expression as its argument.